# GCC -Weffc++ operator overloads returning `*this` and CRTP

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings, crtp, effective-c++

Scott Meyers' *Effective C++* recommends that assignment operators should return a reference to `*this`. GCC's `-Weffc++` seems to generalize this principle to recommend that overloads of in-place arithmetic operators (e.g. prefix `++`) should also return a reference to an instance of the class type.

But for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), GCC apparently fails to recognize then the correct reference type is being returned:

```
template <typename DERIVED>
class Foo
{
  public:
    DERIVED& operator++(void)
    {
      ++data;
      return static_cast<DERIVED&>(*this);
    }

  private:
    int data;
};

class Bar : public Foo<Bar>
{  /* ... */ };
```

Here, `DERIVED&` is the type that really ought to be returned, because `Bar` rather than `Foo<Bar>` is the "real" type of an instance of `Bar`. But GCC gives the following warning:

```
operator_return_this.cpp:5:33: warning: prefix ‘DERIVED& Foo<DERIVED>::operator++()’ should return ‘Foo<DERIVED>&’ [-Weffc++]
         DERIVED& operator++(void)
                                 ^
operator_return_this.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Foo<Bar>’:
operator_return_this.cpp:15:24:   required from here
operator_return_this.cpp:5:18: warning: prefix ‘DERIVED& Foo<DERIVED>::operator++() [with DERIVED = Bar]’ should return ‘Foo<Bar>&’ [-Weffc++]
         DERIVED& operator++(void)
```

The first warning is somewhat sensible--the compiler can't tell that the class is intended to be used for CRTP, so it doesn't realize that `DERIVED` will inherit from `Foo<DERIVED>`. (**EDIT:** Actually, by using a `static_cast` instead of a C-style cast, you *do* ensure that `DERIVED` is really a derived type, so if the compiler postponed issuing this warning until looking at the *implementation* of the function, it could suppress the false positive even without seeing the definition of `Bar`.) But the second warning, where it sees the actual CRTP declaration, doesn't make sense to me at all, since it *should* be able to tell that `Bar&` counts as `Foo<Bar>&`.

But when using CRTP with operator overloading, even the first warning is spurious. Does this mean that `-Weffc++` simply can't be used with CRTP (assuming you want to avoid spurious warnings)?

Comment: I think CRTP should be used there and returning `DERIVED&` is clearly correct.  So all I can see is using a pragma to locally disable that warning.  That is too ugly to be a good "answer" but saying you can't do what the above code wants to do is worse.

Comment: CRTP is basically the non-guaranteed assertion "I will inherit in class X from this class instantiated with X". As it's not guaranteed, your conversion is basically a reinterpret_cast asserting that very same. The compiler is IMO mostly right in complaining, as there's technically nothing that makes it right. Practically, if used correctly, there's nothing wrong either though. Can the compiler be modified to only warn on actual instantiation when it does not actually hold?

Comment: @dascandy Note that the warning is issued on the **function declaration**, *not* where the cast actually occurs. Moreover, a `reinterpret_cast` wouldn't make sense--this should be a `static_cast`, since `Foo<Bar>` is in the inheritance hierarchy of `Bar`. (In fact, putting a `static_cast` here would probably be better, because that *would* guarantee that `DERIVED` is a related type.)

Comment: @dascandy In fact, `static_cast` is indeed a much better choice here, so I've replaced the C-style cast. Note that this has no effect on the warning given.

Comment: @KyleStrand At least that gets you into the realm of "compiler would flag it if this won't work". Why do you want the return type to not match the CRTP class? Is the function logically in the derived class' space? Should its return value be directly usable as the derived class? Because on a whole, this problem will also show on any class that is derived from with an operator...

Comment: @dascandy For CRTP, the so-called "base class" (what you call the "CRTP class")  doesn't exist independently of the derived class. It's not a real type. It would be a surprising API choice for the operator to return a reference of type `Foo<Bar>` rather than simply `Bar` for two reasons: first, because it would be surprising if `(++bar).someMethodOfBar()` failed (you'd need to cast `++bar` *back* to type `Bar`!), and second, because treating `Foo<Bar>` as a "real" type would cause strange effects for type inference.

Comment: @KyleStrand I recently tried to do (std::stringstream() << length).str() and that also does not compile, due to this exact same problem. I would not be surprised if your class does the same thing that this code does.

Comment: @dascandy Oh, on re-reading the whole comment thread I think I understand what you're saying--that the `stringstream` API makes the "surprising" (my word, several comments back) choice of returning `ostream&` instead of `stringstream&` for `operator<<()`. The distinction, though, is that `ostream` is a *real class*, not a *class template*, so CRTP isn't involved at all, and without CRTP (or a similar technique) you can't make the return type for a function in the base class depend on the type of the derived class.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "[my] class [doing] the same thing that this code does", because obviously my class *is* used for CRTP and *does* return a reference to the derived class rather than a reference to the base class (unlike `std::stringstream::operator<<()`, which returns a reference to the base class).